# How to pass a listener within a recyclerview adapter that is in an OnSuccessListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I hope my question makes sense: Basically I have a recycler view within a fragment that I want to open another fragment using Onclick. Because its fragment to fragment I am using an interface/listener within my recyclerview adapter. However I need to pass something in my recyclerView adapter. The problem is that the adapter is in OnCreateView which is within a OnSuccessListener since I am obtaining the location for my app. Therefore I do not know how to pass anything except null for my listener in my adapter. I need to pass a listener within my adapter. I hope this makes sense but here is my code so that it is clear:

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class MessierRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessierRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<MessierData> MessierDataList;
   Context mContext;

private MessierListener messierListener;

public interface MessierListener{
    void onClicked(Bundle bundle);
}





 class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView currentLocation;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        currentLocation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messier_location);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (messierListener !=null) {
            int col = getAdapterPosition();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putDouble("RightAscension", MessierDataList.get(col).getMessierRA());
            bundle.putDouble("Declination", MessierDataList.get(col).getMessierDEC());
            bundle.putDouble("Azimuth", MessierDataList.get(col).getMessierAZ());
            bundle.putDouble("Altitude", MessierDataList.get(col).getMessierALT());
            messierListener.onClicked(bundle);



        }

        }

    }


public MessierRecyclerViewAdapter(List<MessierData> MessierDataList, Context mContext, MessierListener messierListener){
    this.MessierDataList = MessierDataList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.messierListener = messierListener;
}

@Override
public MessierRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.messier_recycler_item,parent, false);



    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( MessierRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.currentLocation.setText(MessierDataList.get(position).getMessierLocation());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return MessierDataList.size() ;
}


}
```

**Fragment Containing the Recycler View (Messier Fragment)**
Its a lot of code so I'll just add the onCreateView which is the issue at the moment:

```
public class MessierFragment extends Fragment implements     
MessierRecyclerViewAdapter.MessierListener {
...
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messier, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.messier_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));



    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();

                Sun sunInstance = new Sun();
                sunInstance.SunmCalculation(longitude, latitude);

                Andromeda andromedaexample = new Andromeda();
                andromedaexample.AndromedaCalculation(latitude);


                messierList();
                messierItems.addAll(messierList());

                adapter = new MessierRecyclerViewAdapter(messierItems, mRecyclerView.getContext(),MessierFragment.this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I try to pass something for the Messier listener in the adapter it brings up a warning from android studio so I'm not sure how to resolve the issue. Right now I have MessierFragment.this which isn't working. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT/WARNING ANDROID STUDIO PROVIDES**

The expected parameter in the adapter: MessierListener

If I use "this" in the adapter in the onCreateView: this (anonymous...android.location.Location>)

I hope this clarifies somewhat the issue is.

Comment: what is the warning?

Comment: please clear your question what u need to pass from which fragment to adapter?

Comment: I added to the description the warning I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, or at least why this code is correct. Based on what I found you have to reference the listener the  host fragment is implementing. Which was why in normal situtations one  put "this" in my adapter to pass that listener on to the recyclerview. However because my adapter is within the OnSuccessListener, "this" references that listener which creates an error. In order to get around that I put in MessierFragment.this and that references the listener the host fragment is implementing.

```
 mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new      
 OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            Sun sunInstance = new Sun();
            sunInstance.SunmCalculation(longitude, latitude);

            Andromeda andromedaexample = new Andromeda();
            andromedaexample.AndromedaCalculation(latitude);


            messierList();
            messierItems.addAll(messierList());

            adapter = new MessierRecyclerViewAdapter(messierItems, mRecyclerView.getContext(),MessierFragment.this);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your question clearly but I think you need to handle action from recycler adapter and communicate between the adapter and its fragment with another fragment

if that correct, you can use EventBus library I think it will help you in many situations

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus,
http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/